# How to upload multiple images in Redactor.js

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image-uploading, redactor, redactor.js

How can I select multiple images in `Redactor.js` in both conditions:

- **drop area** and
- **choose file**

At this time, I am selecting multiple images, multiple times, using **choose file** or **drop area** options.

Comment: did you get any luck with this? if so can you share?